# How to replace a button with an external switch?

Tags: switches, sensor, pwm

I am modifying a kids ride on car. I am trying to add a slow start and slow stop to otherwise very simple system.

Currently it has a on/off pedal, battery and motor - that’s it.

I bought this digital PWM and it has a slow start and slow stop feature. The caveat is - it is triggered by the most right button on the picture on the PWM. To test that it works I hardwired the car pedal and just used this button to start and stop and it worked wonders.

Now I need to somehow connect the pedal to this button.

What are my options here? Is there a terminal or sensor connected to pedal I can solder on in place of this button? Trick is button seems to flip an on/off state, so it’s not an analog gate.

[image: Click to Enlarge]
<sub>Click to Enlarge</sub>

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do: Remove the tact switch (if it's a tact switch, I mean, a momentary switch) from the PWM module. Preferably using a hot air fan combined with a solder iron. In the holes left by the removed switch, solder two cables that you will connect to the pedal. Between the pedal and the PWM module, add a 10K (or 1K if 10K is too much) resistor on each cable in series with the pedal, and a 0.1uF capacitor between cable going to the PWM module and V-. This will protect the PWM module from the electric bounces from the pedal  Then connect the motor to the PWM output as you did.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhjhkN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a great diagram! Would this make the pedal act like a momentary switch in that case meaning I would have to press it to go full power and then disengage and press again to cut power out? At least that’s what the button does at the moment.

Comment: Yes. As I understood, that's how the pedal works in the original set up. Here you replace the button on the PWM board by the pedal.